# Dual output logic gates?

Tags: computer

I know with basic logic gates you see in computing, there are two inputs and one output, essentially allowing for one of two outputs, on or off.

Does anyone know if **dual output** logic gates exist or are even possible? I know if they are possible, they would be *extremely* complex to get to a functioning level but if there is a way to do it, it would potentially allow for three potential options, 0, 1, and 2, which could allow computing to take leaps forward.

If anyone has any input on this, please let me know.

Comment: This might be of interest: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=thrx3SBEpL8 Although not talking about more outputs, it talks about using other number systems to much the same effect, and why we don't. I suppose the reason we don't use multiple output logic gates is analogous.

Comment: Multiple output gates have been around since the stone age of computing, even though they don't mean what you seem to think they mean. You seem to be talking about multi-valued logic. That, too, can be done but there are no advantages to it. Logic simulators, by the way, always simulate multi-valued logic, typically three to seven different possible states.

Comment: As CuriousOne said, dual output is really a confusing term when you mean multi-valued logic, when I read dual output I think of two output signals. But multiple voltage levels are actually used for a few applications such as flash memory (where this allows to hold more than one bit per memory cell). For most applications, however, the decreased noise resistance and more complex circuitry leave no advantage compared to two-level logic.